# How to open a file with already installed application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have written a piece of code that detects installed application in android and opens the file with the application.For example, a word document should be opened with some office apk.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(temp_file);
String type = getMimeType(temp_file.getName());
intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

In the above code **temp_file** is the file that should be opened.And below is the generalised code that I wrote to get the MIME type

```
public static String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }
```

But when I execute ,it throws **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException** exception.So,am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: The correction done by me in the above code->The call to getMimeType method should be:
`String type = getMimeType(data.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getMimeType()` and passing it the file name. But your method `getMimeType()` expects an URL. The documentation for `MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl()` specifically says:

**This method is a convenience method for obtaining the extension of a url and has undefined results for other Strings.**

You are probably getting `null` for the mime type. Add some debug logging and check what `getMimeType()` is returning.

Also, look in the logcat. It should tell you the content of the `Intent` it is trying to resolve. That should also give you a hint.

Comment: Thnx David..
n For others,the solution you provided is only for a fixed MIME type.I was already able to do that.But i wanted to write code that works for all files.May be you all should think to generalize things.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        File file=new File("/sdcard/yourfile");
                        if(file.exists())
                        {
                              Uri path=Uri.fromFile(file);
                              Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                              intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/readername");

                              try
                              {

                                    startActivity(intent);
                              }
                              catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                              {
                                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "No software for PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }
                        }
                  }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
  private void readFile(File file){
     Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");// for .pdf file
         //intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/msword");// for msword file
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 try {
         startActivity(intent);
      } 
     catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         String str=  "No Application Available to View .pdf file.";
         showToast(str);
     }
```

where file is the name of file to be open